# Occasionally, Action leaves the conversation and a google search for the user query is returned instead

Tags: actions-on-google

We have an action where the user can say the name of a company, and the action will return a number of scores for said company. During testing, we have found that the action leaves the conversation and a google search for the queried company is returned instead.

This happens intermittently. More often than not, the action will return the score. Has anyone ever come across this behaviour before?

Behaviour observed on an Android phone and a Google Nest Hub.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [No-Match yielding](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/intents#no-match_yielding), where the Assistant will answer a question that a user asked which your conversation is unable to match. This may because you're using a fallback intent to capture this query, which implicitly signals that your action cannot handle this prompt.

To get around it, you should move to a pattern where you have an intent that [captures free-form text](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/types#custom_types) and ensure that intent gets matched.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the reply. Can no-match yielding take place even if a company has been matched before? I can't actually recreate this on any of my devices, it works as expected. My colleague is experiencing this issue occasionally on his testing devices. Unfortunately, I don't think free-form text would work in our case as we search through an API for company scores. For example, a user query of Microsoft would not return anything as it is listed as Microsoft Corp in the API. We have a company Type with all companies and their respective synonyms, Microsoft being a synonym.

Comment: If an intent is matched, no-match yielding should not happen.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/68396551/4124574), except in my case this used to work perfectly, and then one day the Assistant started answering the intent instead of letting it go to my Action.